# How can I merge the columns from two tables into one output?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables with similar information. Let's call them `items_a` and `items_b`. They should be one, but they are coming from different sources, so they aren't. When I full-join the two table, some rows end up with data from either one or both tables. One of the columns in both tables is `category_id`. I would like to cross the combined table with the categories table using `category_id`. However, I have two `category_id` columns now (one from `items_a` and one from `items_b`). Is there a way to merge the two columns into one?

I hope this isn't too confusing of a question.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Specifying the columns on your query should do the trick:

```
select a.col1, b.col2, a.col3, b.col4, a.category_id 
from items_a a, items_b b 
where a.category_id = b.category_id
```

should do the trick with regards to picking the columns you want.

To get around the fact that some data is only in items_a and some data is only in items_b, you would be able to do:

```
select 
  coalesce(a.col1, b.col1) as col1, 
  coalesce(a.col2, b.col2) as col2,
  coalesce(a.col3, b.col3) as col3,
  a.category_id
from items_a a, items_b b
where a.category_id = b.category_id
```

The coalesce function will return the first non-null value, so for each row if col1 is non null, it'll use that, otherwise it'll get the value from col2, etc.

Comment: can i also use it in where such as:
... where c.col1 = coalesce(a.col1, b.col1)
?

Comment: @bigmac: shouldn't be a problem

Comment: What if there isn't a common id? I just want the columns to join to each other with no common id, simply the order in which they appear?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: That sounds like a different question.  If there is nothing to join the two tables, then relying on the natural order is not guaranteed to give you consistent results.

Comment: What if I would like to check the values from column `a.col1` and column `b.col1` and see if the values are different? If `a.col1` is 0 and `b.col1` is 1, then drop this row. If one of them is null, then use the non-null value. If both are null, keep the null values.

Comment: You can just add an additional where clause.

Answer (score 36):

I guess that what you want to do is an [`UNION`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) of [both tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/typeconv-union-case.html).

If both tables have the same columns then you can just do

```
SELECT category_id, col1, col2, col3
  FROM items_a
UNION 
SELECT category_id, col1, col2, col3 
  FROM items_b
```

Else, you might have to do something like

```
SELECT category_id, col1, col2, col3
  FROM items_a 
UNION 
SELECT category_id, col_1 as col1, col_2 as col2, col_3 as col3
  FROM items_b
```

Comment: Your first example isn't a valid `UNION` statement - it should literally be a combination of two SELECT statements.  The second example doesn't require the brackets and is otherwise syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT col1,
  col2
FROM
  (SELECT rownum X,col_table1 FROM table1) T1
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT rownum Y, col_table2 FROM table2) T2
ON T1.X=T2.Y;
```

Comment: It is hard to read this as an answer to the original question. While the concept may indeed to the right one, it needs some explanation to show show how it relates to the question.

Comment: This answer indeed helped me to combine two columns from two different tables and show them as two different columns in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

The top answer assumes that neither result is null.  In my requirement i had two tables that needed to be made 1 with no join constraint.  I was just combining them.

If you want to get results regardless of 1 is  null or not.

```
select a.col1, b.col2, a.col3, b.col4, a.category_id 
from items_a a
  full outer join items_b b 
  on 1=1
```

Should do the trick.
When i was doing this practically i had to go even further and use table expressions for my two "sets" I wanted to join together and then full outer join the two sets.

Answer (score 0):

select a.categoryname, b.productname, a.categoryid
from categories a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
products b
on a.categoryid = b.categoryid ;

Answer (score 0):

```
select COALESCE(A.CUR_ID, B.CUR_ID, 'OTHER') as CUR_ID 
from (select 'CHF'as CUR_ID) as A 
full outer join (select 'UAD' as CUR_ID) as B
on A.CUR_ID = B.CUR_ID
```

Output:

```text
CUR_ID
CHF
UAD
```

Answer (score -1):

When your are three tables or more, just add union and left outer join:

```
select a.col1, b.col2, a.col3, b.col4, a.category_id 
from 
(
    select category_id from a
    union
    select category_id from b
) as c
left outer join a on a.category_id = c.category_id
left outer join b on b.category_id = c.category_id
```

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem with a small difference: some a.category_id are not in b and some b.category_id are not in a.
To solve this problem just adapt the excelent answer from beny23 to

```
select a.col1, b.col2, a.col3, b.col4, a.category_id 
from items_a a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
items_b b 
on a.category_id = b.category_id
```

Hope this helps someone.
Regards.