# Merging columns from 2 tables to a single table in MS SQL 2014

Tags: sql-server

I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360396/how-can-i-merge-the-columns-from-two-tables-into-one-output) to help me get to where I am, but now my output is wrong.

I have 2 columns, ColumnA from TableA, and ColumnB from Table B. I want TableC consiting of 2 columns, ColumnA and ColumnB. MatchA and MatchB are identical. MatchA is in TableA, MatchB is in TableB. @InputVal is how the values are selected from ColumnA + B. Here is what I have done:

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB
FROM TableA, TableB
WHERE MatchA=MatchB
AND MatchA=@InputVal
```

This produces the output:

```
ColumnA   ColumnB
44        Test1
45        Test1
46        Test1
44        Test2
45        Test2
46        Test2
44        Test3
45        Test3 
46        Test3
```

When, logically, it should be:

```
ColumnA   ColumnB
44        Test1
45        Test2
46        Test3
```

How can I correct my logic to fix the flaw? I've run through many variations of the statement construction and I can't seem to wrap my head around it.
Thanks.

EDIT: User snow_FFFFFF had the solution right, but was missing a part only because I left out a detail.

```
SELECT TableA.ColumnA, TableB.ColumnB
FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.MatchA = TableB.MatchB
AND TableA.SecondMatchA=TableB.SecondMatchB --The change needed
```

Comment: what columns are you trying to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to join your tables:

```
SELECT TableA.ColumnA, TableB.ColumnB
FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.MatchA = TableB.MatchB
```

The INNER JOIN will only return rows from each where there is a match.  A LEFT OUTER JOIN (instead of the INNER JOIN) would give you all rows from TableA and values from TableB where the join was successful.

Right now, you are performing a CROSS JOIN by using the comma between the tables.

Comment: this is what i was thinking, but didnt understand the matcha=matchb part

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but the reason your solution doesn't work is my fault. I left out a secondary variable that must match in order for the process to work. Following with the theme, the solution matches yours except I needed an `AND TableA.SecondMatchA=TableB.SecondMatchB`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use UNION SELECT To Merge Columns From two Tables as below:

```sql
SELECT TableB.ColumnB FROM TableB
UNION ALL
SELECT TableA.ColumnA FROM TableA WHERE TableA.MatchA = @InputVal
```