# how to join two table with where to one column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, database-design

can anyone teach me how to join two tables into one column MySQL
and also is that possible? or not?

Comment: your question is not clear  ..  "  two tables into one column"  ?!? .. update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: sorry mistake but I really want to fetch data from two tables .here is my sample code SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN post_meta ON post_meta.pid=posts.id WHERE (status=1 OR status=4) ORDER BY date DESC and it's giving more columns. my question is it's possible to get all data into one column

Comment: what is the structure of the tables? If each table has only one column id then instead of a select ... where you would need to do a union like select id from posts union select id from post_meta

Comment: Thank you for everyone who came support to me. i solved the problem using "INNER JOIN"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a result as a single column you could use `concat`

```
SELECT concat(p.id, p.status, p.date, m.pid) 
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN post_meta m ON m.pid=p.id 
WHERE (status=1 OR status=4) 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

But you need explicit column (all you need) but not select *

Or could be you are looking for `group_concat`

```
SELECT group_concat(p.title)
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN post_meta m ON m.pid=p.id 
WHERE (status=1 OR status=4)
```

Comment: yes i tried but result  https://ibb.co/ZdRcM0R

Comment: answer  updated .. looking to your sample seems you need  group_concat

Comment: Thanks for everyone who came support to me. i solved the problem using "INNER JOIN"

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Absolutely, join the tables together in SQl(MySql/SqlSvr) is possible.

(INNER) JOIN: Select records that have matching values in both tables.

LEFT (OUTER) JOIN: Select records from the first (left-most) table with matching right table records.

RIGHT (OUTER) JOIN: Select records from the second (right-most) table with matching left table records.

FULL (OUTER) JOIN: Selects all records that match either left or right table records.

All INNER and OUTER keywords are optional.

Let read more about this tutorial.
https://www.dofactory.com/sql/left-outer-join

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be repeat of [How can I merge the columns from two tables into one output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360396/how-can-i-merge-the-columns-from-two-tables-into-one-output)

Provide more details on how you want to join for complete response. An example will be better with input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer

`Select * From table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1;`

You can use `INNER` for getting result where data should be present on both table corresponding to col1

You can use `LEFT` for getting result where data should be present on first table corresponding to col1 but not necessarily present on second table

You can use `RIGHT` for getting result where data should be present on second table corresponding to col1 but not necessarily present on first table

Comment: Thank you for everyone who came support to me. i solved the problem using "INNER JOIN"