# Need to join two tables

Tags: mysql

There is a two tables.

Table 1 columns

```
reservationId
first_name
last_name
```

Table 2 columns

```
reservation_id
username
userid
timestamp
```

My question is table 1 has some previous data.
Table 2 is new one. `Table1.rservationId = Table2.reservation_id`

Need join These two tables,

Why do I need to join? : Need get username field from table2

Condition : If found `Table1.rservationId != Table2.reservation_id data` (Table two is new table, so it's empty) username field should be null and other fields should display correctly.

Comment: you should check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360396/how-can-i-merge-the-columns-from-two-tables-into-one-output

Comment: Read up on joins sepecfically left joins here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: Use Left Join see MYSQL https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: Issue was fixed using left join

SELECT R.reservationId,RF.user_name 
FROM reservation AS R  LEFT JOIN reservation_flow AS RF ON R.reservationId = RF.reservationId
WHERE R.userId = 42
AND R.status NOT IN ('cancelled');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by left join

SELECT R.reservationId,RF.user_name 
FROM reservation AS R  LEFT JOIN reservation_flow AS RF ON R.reservationId = RF.reservationId
WHERE R.userId = 42
AND R.status NOT IN ('cancelled');